# styling host in custom element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, custom-controls, custom-component, shadow-dom

I wrote the below code to get a shadow DOM with text and button, both text and button had been styled correctly, while the host background had been styled in a strange way,

the code is:

```
 // Create a new object based of the HTMLElement prototype
 var fonixDiv = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

// Set up the element.
fonixDiv.createdCallback = function() {
// Create a Shadow Root
var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
    shadow.innerHTML = '\
                        <style>\
                        :host { \
                         border: 2px dashed red;\
                         text-align: left;\
                         font-size: 28px;\
                         background: blue;\
                         }\
                          h3 { color: red; }\
                          button { color: green; }\
                        </style>\
                        <h3>Shadow DOM</h3>\
                        <button id="d">click</button>\
                        ';
      shadow.children.d.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        this.textContent = "you clicked me :(";
        shadow.children[1].textContent="Shadow DOM content changed";
        host.style.background = "green";
        alert("All: button, text and host should be change");
  });
};
```

the output is in the attached.

any help pls.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the background of the host is not BLUE! And why the border is not around the full hist! If I clicked the button the host background will be GREEN as I want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using css file:

the .html file is:

```
<fonix-div></fonix-div>
<div id="host1"></div>
```

the .js file is:

```
// Create a new object based of the HTMLElement prototype
var fonixDiv = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

// Set up the element.
fonixDiv.createdCallback = function() {

// Create a Shadow Root
var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();

    shadow.innerHTML = '<button id="d">click</button>';

       shadow.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log('1: '+this.host.dataset.disabled);
            this.host.dataset.disabled='true';   // set Attribute to the custom element
       });

       shadow.children.d.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            this.textContent = "you clicked me :(";
            shadow.children[1].textContent="Shadow DOM content changed";
            this.disabled=true;
            alert("All: button, text and host should be change");
       });
};

// Register the new element.
var Xfonix =document.registerElement('fonix-div', {prototype: fonixDiv});

var thehost = document.querySelector('#host1');
thehost.appendChild(new Xfonix());
```

the .css file is:

```
body {background: #F7F7F7;}

fonix-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;  
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

fonix-div:hover, fonix-div[data-disabled='true']:hover {background: red;}

fonix-div:Active {background: green;}

fonix-div[data-disabled='true'] {background: green;}

fonix-div::shadow p{color: blue;}
```

the output can be seen [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/hyousef/fyf6thte/7/)